# PDA for $\{a^ib^jc^k \mid (i+j) \bmod 3 = 0, k = i + j\}$

Tags: pushdown-automata

> Construct a pushdown automaton that accepts
> $$\{a^ib^jc^k \mid (i+j)\bmod 3 = 0, k = i + j\}$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $L = \{a^ib^jc^k \mid k = i+j\}$ and let $R = \{ a^ib^jc^k \mid i+j \bmod 3 = 0\}$. The language $L$ is context-free, and presumably you know how to construct a PDA that accepts it. The language $R$ is regular, and presumably you know how to construct a DFA that accepts it. Combine both to obtain a PDA for your language.